# Python Flask: Creating redirect to another website function

Tags: python, web, redirect, flask

I have this problem, where I try to redirect to another URL using FLASK. My HTML form uses POST to get the input to backend:

```
 if request.method == 'POST' and 'redirectButton' in request.form:
    createRedirect(request.form['redirectButton'])
```

And then using my createRedirect func. I would like to redirect them, to URL I have assembled:

```
def createRedirect(videoName):
   redirectLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(VIDEOID[videoname])
   print(redirectLink)
   return redirect(redirectLink, code=302)
```

If I click on the printed link, new tab opens on my explorer and it works fine, but the redirect does not happen -> the URL is right

Also I have no problem with formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 if request.method == 'POST' and 'redirectButton' in request.form:
    redirect_data = createRedirect(request.form['redirectButton']
    return redirect(redirect_data["link"], code=redirect_data["code"])


def createRedirect(videoName):
   redirectLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(VIDEOID[videoname])
   print(redirectLink)
   return {"link": redirectLink, "code": 302}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `return` the redirect.

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect(redirectLink, code=302)
```

Comment: I know, just forgot to type it here, sorry

Comment: @Torimon: but are you returning the `createRedirect()` result?

Comment: try 

```if request.method == 'POST' and 'redirectButton' in request.form:
    return createRedirect(request.form['redirectButton'])```